# How can you create your own default style for a subclassed widget that adds to/overrides the base class's default style, not replaces it?

Tags: java, android, subclass, android-theme, android-styles

### TLDR version

I'm subclassing Android's built-in widgets like TextView, CheckBox and RadioButton and am adding a couple extra properties/attributes.  I also want to specify a default style for each of my subclasses so I can preconfigure these when used.

My question is how can I define my own default style, but have that style be merged with the base-class's default style, not outright replace it?

### Full version

I've been following best-practices for theming our application's custom widgets using the following recommended technique.

Consider the following for a View subclass called MyWidget:

### MyWidget.java

```
public class MyWidget extends View
{
    public MyWidget(Context context)
    {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MyWidget(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs, R.attr.myWidgetStyle);

        TypedArray styledAttrs = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyWidget, R.attr.myWidgetStyle, 0);

        // Only need to read custom attributes here
        // Others are handled in the base class

        styledAttrs.recycle();
    }
}
```

### In attrs.xml

```
<!-- Attribute to hold the default style -->
<attr name="myWidgetStyle" format="reference" />

<!-- Assigning attributes to controls -->
<declare-styleable name="MyWidget">
    <attr name="isRealTime" format="boolean" />
</declare-styleable>
```

### In styles.xml

```
<style name="MyTheme">

    <!-- Store default style in the style-reference attributes -->
    <item name="myWidgetStyle">@style/MyWidget</item>

</style>

<style name="MyWidget">
    <item name="background">@color/someColorResource</item>
    <item name="isRealTime">true</item>
</style>
```

Everything works as expected and my controls pick up the default style as specified.

The problem arises when instead of subclassing View, I instead subclass something like RadioButton.  Using that as an example, since I am manually specifying the defStyleAttr in the call to 'super' in the constructor, my style is replacing the default style entirely and I lose the default appearance of the RadioButton and the dot doesn't appear, just the text.

If I instead don't pass my defStyleAttr to 'super' and only use it when calling obtainStyledAttributes (to handle my custom-defined ones), then any non-custom attributes set in that style (like margins, background, buttonTint, etc.) do not get applied since the base class, which normally handles them, doesn't know about my default style anymore, so it falls back to the base class's default appearance.

The easiest way to address this is of course to base my default style on RadioButton's existing default style via my style's 'parent' property, then when mine becomes the new default, it's the two styles blended with values in mine taking precedence.

The problem there is I don't know what the default style is for the base control (RadioButton in this example) because I have no idea which attribute they're using to hold it (it was *supposed* to be radioButtonStyle but that didn't work), and even if I did know the attribute, that's not what I need.  I need the style which it points to.  (I also tried ?someAttr and ?attr/someAttr' but neither worked.)

Hope you were able to follow that.  Better yet, hope you have an answer for me!

Comment: Styles can have parents. Example: <style name="Widget.MyTextView" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.TextView"> Note: Material theme is available only on Android 5+. Maybe you'd like to extend AppCompat widgets and styles intead.

Comment: Yeah, I'm already extending the AppCompat versions. I also know about (and mentioned in my question) basing styles on others via the style's parent attribute.  But what I don't know is how to get those base styles to use!  In other words, what to actually put in the 'paren't field.  If you do, and can put it in an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem there is I don't know what the default style is for the base control

Widgets and their default styles provided by the AppCompat follow a naming convention. Example: `AppCompatEditText` default style is controlled by the `?editTextStyle` theme attribute which by default points to `@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText`.

Most of the time you can guess the correct name (and the IDE will help you), but if you're looking for a "correct" way of determining the style, follow these steps:

1. Open source of whatever class you're extending, say `AppCompatEditText`.
2. Look into its two-parameter constructor. It calls through to the three-parameter constructor with the third parameter being the default style *theme attribute*. In this case `R.attr.editTextStyle`.
3. Open `values.xml` from the appcompat-v7 library and find the `Theme.AppCompat` definition. It will contain all the default styles. Find which concrete style is referenced by the theme attribute.

It looks like this:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat" parent="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText</item>
    <!-- Other styles... -->
</style>
```

4. Define you own style...

...as extension of the style you found.

```
<style name="Widget.VeryCustomEditText" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
```

If you had extended platform widgets such as `EditText` directly, it would have been a bit different. I'll expand the answer only if necessary.

Comment: Great answer and exactly what I was after.  I would still suggest you expand it for non-AppCompat versions for completeness.  The question itself doesn't dictate one way or another so your answer will most definitely be useful when showing all cases.  But again, this is great!  Thanks!